# Is ECS Task Definition more or less same as POD specification in K8S

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am referring to this article about ECS task definition: [Amazon ECS Task definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html)

> The Docker image to use with each container in your task
>
> How much CPU and memory to use with each task or each container within
> a task
>
> The launch type to use, which determines the infrastructure on which
> your tasks are hosted
>
> The Docker networking mode to use for the containers in your task
>
> The logging configuration to use for your tasks
>
> Whether the task should continue to run if the container finishes or
> fails
>
> The command the container should run when it is started
>
> Any data volumes that should be used with the containers in the task
>
> The IAM role that your tasks should use

If I have to draw any similarity with other orchestration frameworks, the above seems to be closely matching with Kubernetes pod.

So, is ECS Task Definition more or less same as POD specification in K8S????

Comment: Yes, an ECS task and a K8S pod are basically the same thing.

Comment: @MarkB cool.. thx for the confirmation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is YES but more similar to deployment rather than pods.

The longer answer is that ECS task definitions is a way to integrate containers to the AWS ecosystem and provides the configuration and metadata information to the ECS control plane which is AWS's propriety

Comment: I have edited the answer, it is more similar in the concept of a deployment rather than a pod

Comment: that's right, we can specify the number of instances required with deployments but not with pods.

Comment: if you think my answer is qualifying  your question appreciate should you confirm my answer :)

Comment: if S3 interests you - I have another AWS related Q - [In AWS, are S3 and IAM permissions different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64180408/in-aws-are-s3-and-iam-permissions-different)

Comment: I have vast experience and researches running with the above policies and differentiation. Will put my "2 cents" on the question

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the task definition is similar to pod rather than deployment. because deployment in kubernetes defines the replication of the pod/instances, however, pod just defines the template of one instance, and may include several containers, but the pod is the minimum unit in kubernetes. In aws, task definition is the template of the minimum unit of service, and service defines the replication of the tasks.

So pod = task, deployment = task. this is only my understanding. may not exactly.

Comment: I think you meant to say: "pod == task, deployment == service". Cool thought process, I like the comparison.