# In AWS, are S3 and IAM permissions different?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

After creating an S3 bucket in AWS - I want to find out how permissions for Read and Write access to the S3 bucket should be provided?

I am thinking that IAM user permissions and S3 bucket permissions are different. What I am mean is - an IAM user with no permissions on AWS can be granted access to the S3 bucket by just adding him to the S3 buckets permissions for read or read+write accordingly. And S3 permissions have got nothing to do with IAM permissions>

Is the above understanding correct? Please correct and elaborate if the above is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> And S3 permissions have got nothing to do with IAM permissions

This is not the case. The **effective permission** for the bucket and its objects are **union** of the IAM identity based permissions (i.e. those attached to IAM user,role, group) plus bucket policies plus other permissions (SCPs, IAM boundaries), which I don't mention for simplicity.

By default bucket and objects are private. You can `Allow` access to them using either IAM policies, bucket policies or both. Effective permissions will be the union of all these individual permissions. This means that you can use bucket policy to grant access to `object1` and IAM policy to grant access to `object2` to the same IAM user. The said user will be able to access **both objects**.

This behavior changes when there is `Deny`, as **deny always wins**. So an IAM user can have `Allow` in IAM policies to a given bucket, but the bucket can have `Deny` for that user. The result will be `Deny` always.

Subsequently, all these mean that bucket polices and IAM permissions should be considered together and are inter-connected with each other. Thus, you **can't say** that "S3 permissions have got nothing to do with IAM permissions".

Answer (score 0):

An **IAM User** has no permissions by default. If they wish to do *anything* via an authenticated API call, they must be granted permission to do so.

Even if an Amazon S3 bucket policy grants access to an IAM User, they cannot access content in Amazon S3 unless their IAM permissions allow them to make the associated API call (eg `ListBuckets` or `GetObject`).

Please note that I am referring to an **authenticated API call**, *not* an Anonymous HTTP requests via a web browser URL.

A **Bucket Policy** can grant "public access" by referring to `"Principal": "*"` (which means that even unauthenticated users can retrieve content via a URL), or it can grant access to specific IAM Users and IAM Roles. However, if that user/role doesn't have permission to call any S3 Actions, then they cannot access the bucket.

A `Deny` policy from either IAM or a Bucket Policy takes precedence over `Allow`. So, an IAM User with permission to access a bucket can be denied by the Bucket Policy, and vice versa.

Comment: without touching the S3 bucket permissions, how can an IAM user be granted full access to a bucket say `big-bucket`. When the bucket - `big-bucket` is created in S3, does any IAM permissions also get created (specific to `big-bucket`), using which access can be granted to an IAM user.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning - `ListBuckets` and `GetObject` permissions,  these are generic, not specific to a bucket. Are there any other/more generic permissions (related to S3) one got to know.

Comment: Bucket Policies apply only to the bucket to which they are attached. IAM permissions can also be limited to specific buckets. See: [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

Answer (score 0):

In AWS IAM is the place to generate all policies and to assign them to users and/or roles.
As a general rule, AWS recommends using S3 bucket policies or IAM policies for access control.

> **"S3 ACLs are a legacy access control mechanism that predates IAM. However, if you already use S3 ACLs and you find them sufficient,
> there is no need to change."**

By default, a user/role is assuming the policies provided by an SCP which stands for "service control policy". It is very similar to the policies you probably faced but this is provided by the account level/or organization level.

Among all options to generate and assume policies, there is a logical "and" which mean that in case there is at least 1 "deny" among the policies it will restrict access of a user/role to a specific bucket for instance in your case